# Unwanted Toast Notifications

Tags: notifications

Android 4.0 3. HTC Sense 3.6. I have some app installed on my SD card (1 of 195), that pops up a toast notification on boot/SD mount that says "Have a good day!" And lasts for nearly a minute. Does anyone know an easy way for me to figure out what app is causing that? Since toasts aren't a permission, an app like addon detector won't work. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like there's an app that is listening for the permission `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` and firing the toast much to your annoyance.

You need to check with yourself by asking yourself those two vital questions -

- When did this happen?
- What was the last app you installed?

And backtrace it to the offending app. For an example, check out [this](http://lifehacker.com/5888034/aspotcat-shows-all-your-android-apps-permissions-services-that-cost-you-money) and narrow it down to that aforementioned permission and see which one is it and un-install it.

Comment: If your device is rooted, you can also check with [Autorun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun) which app established listeners for BOOT_COMPLETED *AND* the media mount (don't remember the intent for that at the moment).